# Autowire ObjectMapper in Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I need to use default ObjectMapper inside my Spring-boot application as a singleton instance. Can I simply @autowire the ObjectMapper(Which instance created by default in Spring-boot application) inside my application without creating a @Bean(As I don't want to change any functionalities of ObjectMapper)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: yes you can autowire

Comment: @pvpkiran By autowire will it return the same ObjectMapper bean used by default in Spring-boot.

Comment: So it will act like a singleton one right..??

Comment: Yes it will return the same instance

Comment: @pvpkiran   Is there any way(doc) to find the beans that created default by the spring-boot application..?

Comment: No, there is no such doc. There are way too many. You can just Autowire  ApplicationContext in a class and get all the beans

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

Yes, you can.

**Explanation**

The reason for that is that Spring uses "auto-configuration" and will instantiate that bean for you (as was mentioned) if you haven't created your own. The "instantiation" logic resides inside `JacksonAutoConfiguration.java` ([github link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L101)). As you can see, it is a `@Bean` annotated method with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation where the magic happens. It's no different than any other beans auto span up by Spring.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to change the funcuntallty, you can just return the Default `ObjectMapper`

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't want to create an ObjectMapperConfig class and return a bean like your sample. Can I just autowire the default objectMapper which is already created by SpringBoot?

Comment: Try it without the @scope annotation

Comment: Do I really need to create a Bean..?

Comment: If you want to autowire the objectmapper, and spring didn’t create already a beam of that, then yes

Comment: Yes, That's I really wanted to know. I listed out the bean list and ObjectMapper is also created by Spring. So this means I don't to create a separate bean right.?

Answer (score 1):

If you know something else is creating it, yes you can just autowire and use it in  your bean

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;

@PostConstruct
public ObjectMapper configureMapper() {
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);

    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS, true);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}
```