# Spring Boot 2.5.0 and InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

After update from Spring Boot 2.4.5 to Spring 2.5.0 I noticed the following exceptions in the application logs:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update["my_chat_member"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.ChatMemberUpdated["new_chat_member"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.ChatMember["untilDateAsInstant"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnsupportedTypeSerializer.serialize(UnsupportedTypeSerializer.java:35) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1215) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1059) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar!/:2.12.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.mapToTextMessage(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:279) ~[spring-jms-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.toMessage(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:184) ~[spring-jms-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I reverted to Spring Boot 2.4.5 and not everything works fine. What may be wrong with Spring Boot 2.5.0 ?

**Updated**

The corresponding GitHub https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26859

Comment: Just adding the dependency is not enough. You need to configure the object mapper to add the Jackson module

Comment: But why it is working in SB 2.4.5 in stopped working in 2.5.0 ?

Comment: Could conceivably be [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b1f3d91f7df5dd311bf7e835cf6df003865a069c). If so, it's a bug

Comment: Kind of looks like the copy might screw things up. If you're appending your time module to the ObjectMapper after this copy happens, then the copied mapper won't pick up your change (obviously). Previously, you would just be mutating the instance held by the `JacksonClusterEnvironmentBuilderCustomizer`, which is fine so long as ObjectMapper is thread-safe, which it is

Comment: Thanks. So, should I wait for the newer version of SB in order to get it solved or how ?

Comment: Personally I would wait until the next release.  In addition to this issue, 2.5.0 also broke our application due to: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26627

Comment: @PatrickHerrera Spring Boot 2.5.1 was released. Did this release solve the mentioned bugs?

Comment: Looks like the issue with 'Java 8 date/time type' has not yet been resolved

Comment: 2.4.5 and 2.5.1 use different versions of Jackson. I suspect that Maven may have corrupted the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` jar when it downloaded it. I would try clearing Maven’s local cache and building your application again.

Comment: For the record, the copying of the ObjectMapper is specific to Couchbase and, judging by the stack trace, it is JMS not Couchbase that’s involved here.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks for your answer! I completely wiped my local Maven repo and redownloaded it from scratch. After this I'd like to confirm that the issue still exists

Comment: Thanks for trying that. Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only able to catch such exception during execution of the application and receiving messages from Telegram API

Comment: For me - the /actuator/info endpoint stopped working after upgrading to sb 2.5.1, and fail with the same InvalidDefinitionException and jsr310 error regarding Instant type. 
Is the commit pointed by @Michael solved this issue ?

Comment: The commit pointed to be @Michael is completely unrelated to the Actuator's info endpoint

Comment: I don't have `Jackson2ObjectMappearBuilder' on the application classpath in 2.4.5 and everything works correctly. Do I need to have `Jackson2ObjectMappearBuilder` on the classpath with SB 2.5.1 and if so, what Maven dependecy should I use for this purpose?

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson I'm testing right now, but looks like the issue is that I don't have `spring-web` Maven dependency on my application classpath. Anyway, I added `spring-web` Maven dependency to test this issue - but my Spring Boot application doesn't need `spring-web` because this is Telegram Bot

Comment: Unfortunately, adding spring-web to the classpath didn't help :(

Comment: If you weren’t using `spring-web` then Spring Boot won’t have been involved in configuring Jackson. Without it, `Jacskon2ObjectMapperBuilder`won’t be available and Boot’s Jackson auto-configuration will back off.

Comment: I added spring-web but it didn’t help with this issue

Comment: @alexanoid No, 2.5.1 didn't fix it for me, but it turns out the issue was that in some tests we were creating ObjectMappers from scratch that didn't have the right modules registered.  Fixing that fixed the problem (and I didn't need to add `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` as an explicit dependency either).
Still not sure why this was never an issue before, but this fix should prevent future issues

Comment: @AndyWilkinson you were right. After deep investigation I found the following code in the 3rdparty library `= new ObjectMapper();`  I added the following fix `ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());` and the issue is gone. Thank you!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I saw an issue in one of my test classes. The problem there was it was creating a new ObjectMapper instance that was not adding the JavaTimeModule.

Here is a sample test that works in Spring 2.4.5 but fails in 2.5.0/2.5.1 with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` not supported by default

It might be due to the upgrade in the jackson-datatype-jsr310 version

```
package net.jpmchase.gti.gtfabric;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class ObjectMapperTest {

    @Test
    public void objectMapperTest() throws Exception{

        ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now();
        ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
        o.writeValueAsString(time);
    }
}
```

To fix this particular test case had to add an explicit

```
ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
o.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: Try to use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` class to build instances of the `ObjectMapper` class: `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build()`. In this case you would obtain properly configured mappers. Wherever you have Spring Context, you could also inject a bean of  `ObjectMapper` which Spring Boot exposes via `JacksonAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: I had this problem evaluating values on unit test and this fixed it doing
```new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).writeValueAsString(value);```
 :D thanks

Comment: @TuGordoBello aggree and advice to use the fluent-mutator to initialize in one line: [`new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#registerModule(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module)).

Comment: This isn't an answer just tells you how to reproduce the issue. Doesn't help if your dependecies are using ObjectMapper. Nothing will stop spring from picking up the broken ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you are not using in your code Object Mapper provided by spring.

Wrong way:

```
ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
```

Correct way:

```
@Autowired
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder;
```

...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = mapperBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Can you explain, why the constructor use is considered wrong and with injected builder correct ?

Comment: If you are creating an instance yourself, you will need to configure everything yourself, for example add all the extensions you need. Using the builder provided by Spring, you have everything set up.

Comment: Would add this great explanation to your answer ️ Spring's auto-configuration already registers available modules like `JavaTimeModule` to its default `ObjectMapper` bean. You can simply use this by adding a field to the test-class: `@Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;` (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64297951/5730279)). I would only use the _builder_ if Spring's auto-configured `ObjectMapper` is not sufficient and I need to [customize a separate one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper).

Comment: Not helpful because you can't change your depdencies code to use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Spring Data Couchbase then this might be your problem:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blame/4.2.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration.java#L309

The bug report is here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1209

This has been fixed in Spring-Data-Couchbase 4.3

Answer (score 2):

Posting a proper answer for the future me (that forgets):

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).findAndRegisterModules();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
            serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factory.setSerializer(serializer);
            return factory.getObject();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Spring 3.1.2, after trying different approaches the solution that worked for me was composed of 2 changes:

- Adding the dependency as follows (this project uses gradle)

`implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.2'`

- Adding this annotation to the Instant property that was causing the problem

`@JsonSerialize(using = InstantSerializer.class)`

Answer (score 0):

While both Saifuddin Merchant and Dawid Świtoń-Maniakowski have provided different but equally working ways to make the library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

actually work, my proposal is to remove it from your `pom.xml` completely and to write your own serializer (*as an inner static class in this example*):

```
public static class CustomDateSerializer extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4365897561L;
        public CustomDateSerializer() { 
            this(null); 
        } 
        public CustomDateSerializer(Class<LocalDateTime> t) {
            super(t); 
        }
        @Override
        public void serialize(
                LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            gen.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")));
        }
    }
```

Next, annotate the time field of the object you want to serialize as JSON:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Not much of code, right? The `pom.xml` dependency is 5 lines of code itself. But then autowiring `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` is 2 lines, or if you decide to go with registering `new JavaTimeModule()` then it would be much more lines of code since this JavaTimeModule provides inappropriate date time serialization (as an array of numbers!) out of the box, so you would be in need to wire your own formatter into this `JavaTimeModule` somehow... not what you want probably.

Watch out for the generic type of the custom serializer - it is suited for `<LocalDateTime>` here. Just modify it to fit your needs.